# Firebase update database

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to make an HTML game and I'd like to add a leaderboard based on the player's scores. I'm using firebase to host my website and I'm not sure how to use the database properly.

This is the firebase class that I'd be using to call the database

```
const config = {
    apiKey: //MyApiKey,
    authDomain: "daball.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://daball.firebaseio.com/",
    storageBucket: "gs://daball.appspot.com"
};

class Firebase {
    constructor() {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        this.auth = firebase.auth();
        this.storage = firebase.storage()
        this.db = firebase.database()
    }

}

export default Firebase;
```

And this is currently the database JSON file.

```
{
  "leaderboard": [null, {
    "id": "aaa",
    "score": 5
  }, {
    "id": "bbb",
    "score": 4
  }, {
    "id": "ccc",
    "score": 3
  }, {
    "id": "ddd",
    "score": 2
  }, {
    "id": "eee",
    "score": 1
  }]
}
```

I'd want to check when a score is greater than one of the existing ones reading the database and updating the leaderboard and therefore the database. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the problem you have while implementing the use-case?

Comment: I don't know how to read and write in my database properly

Comment: Did you try anythnign yet? If not, it is unlikely we will explain things better than the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write or one of the **many** existing tutorials out there.